# How Can I get My Discord Bot To Send A Cleaner Message To Server

Tags: python, discord.py

I have built a discord bot that connects to a sqlite3 database, and holds special coordinates for a Minecraft realm.  Here is the code I am referencing in this issue:

```
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

connection = sqlite3.connect("mc_coords.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

createTable = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
mcCoords(coord_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, coords TEXT, coord_name TEXT)"""

cursor.execute(createTable)

@bot.command(name='coords', help = 'Responds with a list of all of the coordinates added to the list')
async def coordinates(ctx):
    getCoords = f"""SELECT coord_name, coords FROM mcCoords"""
    with connection:
        cursor.execute(getCoords)
    coords = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(coords) < 1:
        await ctx.send("There are currently no coordinates in the list")
        return
    print(coords)
    await ctx.send(coords)
```

When I call use the command in discord, it correctly retrieves the data in the database but returns it as a tuple, like so:

```
[('water monument', '1160 61 -1747'), ('test', '123 456 789')]
```

I want the data above to be returning in a nicer format like so:

```
water monument: 1160 51 -1747
test: 123 456 789
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shortest Method**

```py
f_msg = '\n'.join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in coords)
await ctx.send(f_mesg)
```

Delete `await ctx.send(coords)` and add these two lines.

If you want to make the **keys** bold,

```
f_msg = '\n'.join(f"**{k}:** {v}" for k, v in coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Here I assign `coords` as a variable just to mock the data, in your case leave that line out.)

Instead of sending the data as returned, reformat it:

```py
coords = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d"), ("e", "f")] #any number of tuples
string_to_send = "\n".join([f"{place}: {coord}" for place, coord in coords])
print(string_to_send)
```

This prints:

```
a: b
c: d
e: f
```

Unrelated: You should also consider using embeds to make the message prettier.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a function for this but if I face to this problem I would do this:

```py
for coord in coords:
    for i in range(0, coord.count("(")+1):
        coord = str(coord).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", ":")
    print(coord)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary here.

```
water monument: 1160 51 -1747
test: 123 456 789
```

The above output is in key value format which is being used in Dictionary.
The best part here is only tuples can be used to form a dictionary because they are immutable.

And, In your case we are getting tuples. Hence can return a Dictionary instead of tuple here.

Example :

```
import string 

string.ascii_lowercase

{item: ix for ix, item in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase,1)}
```

This returns output as :

{**'A': 1,
'B': 2,
'C': 3,
'D': 4,
'E': 5,........**} Which is a dictionary.

Here, **ix** is my *enumerator* and **item** is my *alphabets*. I return it in the form of `item : ix` which is of `key : Value` format.

Return you output in Dictionary by using Curly Braces i.e. `{ }`